# Strange parse error with static concatenated string variable

Tags: php, string, static, concatenation, parse-error

I'm getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';' in /var/(...)/config.php on line 5

With this (simplified) code:

```
<?php

class Config
{
   public static $somevar = "Date: " . date('Y');
}

?>
```

I thought this was valid php, but I guess not... what am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php):

> Like any other PHP static variable, static properties may only be initialized using a literal or constant; expressions are not allowed. So while you may initialize a static property to an integer or array (for instance), you may not initialize it to another variable, to a function return value, or to an object.

Try writing

```
Config::$somevar = "Date: " . date('Y');
```

after the class definition.

Answer (score 2):

No operation or function is allow for property initialization, because this is evaluated when parsing.

Answer (score 1):

From [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

> Like any other PHP static variable, static properties may only be initialized using a literal or constant; expressions are not allowed. So while you may initialize a static property to an integer or array (for instance), you may not initialize it to another variable, to a function return value, or to an object.