# PhP: Breaking an array into more lines

Tags: php, arrays

I am programming php since lot's of years. Now I have a new wish. I want to make an array with a long string more readable:

```
$var = array( 'help' => 'This is a very long help text. This is a very long help text. This is a very long help text.');
```

First try: I have tried this without success:

```
$var = array( 'help' => 'This is a very long help text.'
. 'This is a very long help text.'
. 'This is a very long help text.');
```

Second try: And I have tried this without success:

```
$var = array( 'help' => 'This is a very long help text.' . 'This is a very long help text. This is a very long help text.');
```

By the way: There is **no chance** to build the string before, I have to do it in this line. How can I break the array into more lines?

I was asked to show the real example, here it is:

```
class JKWerte {
   public static $purifyoptions = array(
     'HTML.Allowed' => 'table, thead, tbody, tfoot, th, tr, td, img[src|alt], div, span, p, br, ul, ol, li, *[class], *[style], *[height], *[width], h1, h2, h3, h4, a[href|title], b, i, em, strong' );

   public function test() {

   }
}
```

The variable is an attribute of a class and I call it with
    JKWerte::purifyoptions;

Comment: *How can I break the array into more lines?* You mean in the code into multiple lines or in multiple elements??

Comment: "In the code" but I am also interested "in multiple elements".

Comment: Just looked again at your code and both attempts should just work fine! Do you get any errors? Add error reporting: `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>`

Comment: Both examples execute fine for me on the command line. A clearer definition of "without success" would be helpful.

Comment: So you just can concatenate your strings as you did in your first attempt where is the problem?

Comment: I don't think you can have a full stop in an array index.

Comment: I have turned error-reporting on and I don't get an error. I have put my real example above into my first post. The variable is an attribute of a class and I call it with JKWerte::purifyoptions;

Comment: I still don't see your goal? Are you trying to define the array just over multiple lines OR are you trying to split the long text into multiple elements?

Comment: My goal: multiple lines

Comment: And what's wrong with your first attempt? Works fine for me?!

Comment: One more information, I am working with a php-framework (Yii) but I think that is not important, it is a "normal" php-problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static class variables may not be initialized with expressions in PHP.

Here is one way to split the string via HEREDOC-Syntax, so long as it may contain additional spaces and linebreaks:

```
<?php
class JKWerte {
   public static $purifyoptions = array(
     'HTML.Allowed' => <<<EOT
     table, thead, tbody, 
     tfoot, th, tr, td,
     img[src|alt], div,
     span, p, br, ul, ol,
     li, *[class], *[style],
     *[height], *[width], h1,
     h2, h3, h4, a[href|title],
     b, i, em, strong
EOT
   );

   public function test() { }
}

var_dump(JKWerte::$purifyoptions);
?>
```

Outputs:

```
array(1) {
  ["HTML.Allowed"]=>
  string(213) "     table, thead, tbody, 
     tfoot, th, tr, td,
     img[src|alt], div,
     span, p, br, ul, ol,
     li, *[class], *[style],
     *[height], *[width], h1,
     h2, h3, h4, a[href|title],
     b, i, em, strong"
}
```

Alternatively you can define the content of your static variable later, e.g. after the class definition:

```
<?php
class JKWerte {
   public static $purifyoptions = array(
     'HTML.Allowed' => ''
   );

   public function test() { }
}

JKWerte::$purifyoptions['HTML.Allowed'] = 'table, thead, tbody, '
     .'tfoot, th, tr, td, '
     .'img[src|alt], div, '
     .'span, p, br, ul, ol, '
     .'li, *[class], *[style], '
     .'*[height], *[width], h1, '
     .'h2, h3, h4, a[href|title], '
     .'b, i, em, strong';

var_dump(JKWerte::$purifyoptions)
?>
```

Outputs:

```
array(1) {
  ["HTML.Allowed"]=>
  string(172) "table, thead, tbody, tfoot, th, tr, td, img[src|alt], div, span, p, br, ul, ol, li, *[class], *[style], *[height], *[width], h1, h2, h3, h4, a[href|title], b, i, em, strong"
}
```

Comment: And where is the problem that OP concatenates the strings? *Static class variables may not be initialized with expressions in PHP* Do you have a  (official)manual link for this?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267050/strange-parse-error-with-static-concatenated-string-variable) stackoverflow question for the quote from the manual.

Comment: All other solutions don't work (at least for me) - I also tried without yii-framework. But the two alternatives from user3760780 work fine, thanx!

Comment: Rizier123 I am also interested in your solution. Could you copy the whole code  into an answer? I will test it here.

Comment: @Didgejo You're code which you show us here works just completely 100% fine! OR wait... Is PHP <5.6 `echo phpversion();` ?